# converting json object value into tuple in python

Tags: python, json, list, tuples

I have json file as (test.json)

```
{
    "items": [{
        "instrument_name": "ABERDEEN",
        "country_desc": "United Kingdom",
        "region_desc": "Europe"
    }, {
        "instrument_name": "HLDGS LTD",
        "country_desc": "China",
        "region_desc": "APxJ"
    }, {
        "instrument_name": "RONS INC A",
        "country_desc": "United States",
        "region_desc": "US"
    }]
}
```

i want to convert it into list of tuple i.e.

```
[("ABERDEEN","United Kingdom","Europe"),("HLDGS LTD","China","APxJ"),("RONS INC A","United States","US")]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
x={
    "items": [{
        "instrument_name": "ABERDEEN",
        "country_desc": "United Kingdom",
        "region_desc": "Europe"
    }, {
        "instrument_name": "HLDGS LTD",
        "country_desc": "China",
        "region_desc": "APxJ"
    }, {
        "instrument_name": "RONS INC A",
        "country_desc": "United States",
        "region_desc": "US"
    }]
}
items=x["items"]

[tuple(item.values()) for item in items]
```